# Input tag collapsing when I hover over it. Co-worker has same github repo and his works

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx, css-grid

As you'll see below in my code, my React project has a bug where when I hover over a search bar, using an input tag w/type text, it collapses and I cannot type into it. My co-workers works perfectly fine. Our code is the same. Here it is.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 2em 4em 16em repeat(3, 2em);
}

.search-bar {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  outline-color: white;
  outline-width: 1.5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid white;
  grid-row: 4;
  grid-column: 3 / 7;
}
```

```html
<div className="wrapper">
  <div className="title">
    <h1>Placeholder<span className="blue-period">.</span></h1>
  </div>
  <div className="login">
    <h4>Here's our login page!</h4>
    <a href="http://localhost:8080/login"><button className="login-btn">Login with Spotify</button></a>
  </div>
  <input placeholder="Search a song" className="search-bar" type="text" />
</div>
```

The page loads normally and the search bar appears fine. Right when you hover over it, it will collapse.

Comment: If you remove the CSS, does it still collapse?

Comment: Have you inspected it to see if there are any CSS changes upon hovering? Have you activated break points to see if it is JS collapsing it etc?

Comment: @thomas what is the purpose of making it a snippet. Clearly, this does not enhance the situation

Comment: @ProEvilz, as a matter of reproducing the Error. For me this works in FF, Chrome and Edge without collapsing. If Nate can reproduce the Error with this snippet, my best guess would be, that his problem is due to a plugin in his browser rather than a CSS problem. And If he can't, I'd ask him to update the code, until the snippet reproduces the Error.

Comment: By looking at the code, it is obvious it wouldn't collapse... there is nothing in the CSS to collapse it.

Comment: Removing the css is fine. When I remove the .wrapper css class it works like it should. When I add the .wrapper class back the input collapses into a tiny little box you can't type into.

Comment: My partner's doesn't have a height or width inside the .search-bar class. I reactivated the .wrapper class and added a height and width to the search bar and now it is working ok. I don't understand why the search bar won't take the width from the grid columns that I have in place.